# Allow another role to edit only parts of any node

Tags: 7, users

I have nodes with a "topic" field that is a taxonomy reference. Nodes are submitted by users and users can only edit their own nodes.

How can I allow a "moderator" role to be able to edit the topic fields for any nodes but not any other fields on those nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module will allow you to do exactly this.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.